# SIP buttons not showing on WM6.5 emulator and Windows handheld 6.5 (Motorola MC65)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola, windows-embedded

I've had this Motorola MC65 handheld for a while and was trying to migrate a program that I wrote in C# with VS2008 which ran perfect on a WinCE device on to it. However I encountered a problem that I had no idea at all where to start with.

Please see the screen shots. Picture 1 is my program (please ignore the squares they were just Asian chars). There is no close button on it whatsoever. At the right bottom corner there's just an input method icon. I wasn't trying to hide the windows title bar. On Windows CE device and PocketPC emulator the close button shows as expected, as Picture 2.

The system on the MC65 is Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 so I'm not sure if it's okay to use the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 SDK/emulator for development? And also, can I somehow make the program show as in WinCE system where the title bar with the control boxes on top, just like a PC?

Thanks in advance.

Picutre 1 [NoSIP](http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y517/chinalionet/NoSIp_zpsd97e726d.png)

Picture 2 [Pocket PC](http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y517/chinalionet/POCKETPC_zpsa948c7f5.jpg)

Comment: the nav buttons can be disabled via the registry, could be a place to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The system on the MC65 is Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 so I'm not sure if it's okay to use the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 SDK/emulator for development?"
The WEH 6.5.3 is the right emulator for a Windows Embedded handheld 6.5 device.

The issue you are seeing is a change in the UI and a difference between Windows CE and Windows Mobile:
a) WEH natively supports a menu bar. If you do not have a menu bar, you will have no SIP (and no Start and OK/X button).
b) Windows CE uses command bars for menu implementation. see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.wince/G7Oi5Kofda4 and !!!! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2564/Window-Wrapper-for-a-WinCE-Win-dialog-app

Now, it is up to you to re-design for WEH/WCE compatibilty or switch to WEH.

Comment: Thanks man. Having a menu bar is the way to go. However if I have three or four menu items the OK button will be "pushed out" of the menu. I would probably need to associate the Exit action to one of my menu items. Am I right?

Comment: The WEH menu is designed for having to have only two main menu items. OTOH it is no fault to not use the OK button and have a File-Exit option. There are different possiblities to have OK/X or nothing: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/05/10/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-series-part-1/